# Understanding Evaluation Periods and Datapoints to Alarm

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

I kinda struggle understanding what happens in our AWS CloudWatch alarms setup.

We're watching the number of available nodes in ElasticSearch. The goal is to raise an alarm when available nodes is less than three for more than 2 hours.

Here's the alarm definition:
[image: alarm definition]

But still the alarm is triggered even when the available nodes number drops down for just a while:

[image: alarm graph]

When period is set to 1 hour the graph looks as follows:

[image: alarm graph hourly period]

According to the [AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/AlarmThatSendsEmail.html) I'd expect the alarm to be triggered when the available nodes is <= 2 for two periods (2 hours).

Can anyone explain what is wrong here?

Comment: What does the graph look like if you set the period to 1 hour, are you using min, max, avg for the alarm?

Comment: I'm using minimum (can be seen in first image under "Statistic"). Updated the question to contain the graph when period is set to 1 hour.

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem here is that the period is 1 hour. If it goes down to two nodes within one hour it will go on the alarm state.

If you want to evaluate every two hours, you can try to set your evaluation periods to 2 with period of 1 hour or to 1 with a period of 2 hours.